# Tool to keep duplicate information in source code repository consistent

Tags: software-development, command-line, text-processing, source-code, templating

Sometimes it can't be avoided to duplicate information in a source code repository: E.g. parts of the `README` file will often be duplicated in the full documentation, the current version will often be duplicated between a constant in the source code and a field in the project metadata, etc. Ideally, the tools that deal with the information in question (e.g. documentation systems for the docs, build systems for the package metadata, ...) would be able to help with single-sourcing such information, but they are often too limited to get rid of *all* duplication, so you end up needing to keep some of it in sync manually.

So: **Are there any generic / language-agnostic tools that help with keeping such duplicate information in sync?**

Similar to how [cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) is a language-agnostic tool for templating out repositories initially, except the tool I'm looking for here would be meant to be run regularly as part of CI or as a pre-commit hook.

Features that would be nice:

- be able to mark block of text to keep in sync with special comments, a la [Ansible's blockinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html)
- in files with strict formats that don't allow comments, be able to find the lines to replace based on e.g. a regex or prefix instead
- maybe one mode of operation that just regenerates the whole file based on some template
- can be run in "check mode" in which no replacements are made and it is only checked whether everything is in sync (useful e.g. for CI or pre-commit hooks)
- perhaps support different "sources" of where the information to sync should come from:

  - "single source of truth" config in a format specified by the tool itself (easy)
  - parsed (e.g. via user-specified regex) from one of the files where it actually appears in the repo

It should be a command-line tool obviously.